# SELECT a single record with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select a single record using from two tables. But if you use `SIMPLE JOIN`, it will only returns the value when the condition satisfies both the table and when we use `LEFT` or `RIGHT JOIN` also, it will return all the values from the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` table.

I'm using the following query,

`SELECT *
FROM activity_feeds
LEFT OUTER JOIN activity_traders ON activity_feeds.feed_id = activity_traders.trdr_feed_id = '11'`

I need to get the values from both tables only when `activity_feeds.feed_id = activity_traders.trdr_feed_id = '11'` and when the value does not matches with the right table, it should return null for the columns in the right table. Please help!

Edit:Table structures added

**Feeds**

[image]

**Traders**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that all the records are based from `activity_feeds` whether or not the `feed_id` exists on  `activity_traders` table as long as it will display all `feed_id` that has a value of `11`. Try this one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   activity_feeds a
           LEFT OUTER JOIN  activity_traders b
                ON a.feed_id = b.trdr_feed_id 
WHERE  a.feed_id = '11'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM activity_feeds LEFT OUTER JOIN activity_traders ON activity_feeds.feed_id = 
activity_traders.trdr_feed_id where activity_traders.trdr_feed_id  = '11'
```

Comment: No it didn't works. You can check the table structures above.

Comment: The where condition should be on first table's feed id, since we are selecting based on that

Comment: it sometimes return an empty set because `activity_traders.trdr_feed_id` may or may not contain record id from `activity_feeds`

Answer (score 0):

```
ON activity_feeds.feed_id = activity_traders.trdr_feed_id 
WHERE activity_traders.trdr_feed_id = '11'
```